# How to ensure that the colors defined in the CSS file are used?

Tags: eclipse, swt, e4

There is a common thorny problem in `SWT`: the background color obtained by `getBackground()` may not be the same as the color it **actually** displays.

As stated in these two issues [**1**](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/issues/618) [**2**](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/issues/707) .

After reading some source code, I think the solution to this problem is a bit tricky, and it has to do with the various design principles of SWT for background colors. So this may not be solved for a while.

But it seems that one of the more foolproof solutions is：

```java
control.setBackground( control.getBackground() ) ;
```

In this way, the given color becomes the value of the field `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.background` and has a higher priority when the control is rendered using the background color.

So here's the question, CSS uniformly does the following when applying background colors：

```java
// org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.helpers.CSSSWTColorHelper.setBackground(Control, Color)
/** Helper function to avoid setting colors unnecessarily */
public static void setBackground(Control control, Color newColor) {
    if (!Objects.equals(control.getBackground(), newColor)) {
        control.setBackground(newColor);
    }
}
```

This would run into the problem described at the beginning, resulting in the desired color in the CSS file not actually appearing in the interface.

One way I can think of is to hack this code in my program:

```java
public static void setBackground(Control control, Color newColor) {
    control.setBackground(newColor);
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it ?

Comment: I doubt that this can be done. On macOS this would not even be desirable as the colour of highlights in several controls changes when the system accent preference is changed and a proper mac app should respect that.

Comment: I think that in order to respect this (colors follow the system dynamically), then the background color of a control should not be explicitly defined in the CSS file. If it is explicitly defined in the CSS file, reflecting the stronger desire of the definer for this, then the program should respect it more.